# How to restore Cassandra snapshots into smaller cluser

Tags: linux, cassandra

If I make snapshots on every node in 10 node cluster, how to restore them into 5 node cluster where every node has stronger CPU and more storeage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional way to restore sstable backups is by copying the sstable files to the data directory and calling 'refresh' to load the data into the running cluster. If the topology has changed, if you're unable to access the data directory, if you have filename collisions, or if you don't have sufficient room or time to deal with lots of nodes having a ton of data they don't own, then nodetool refresh may be less than ideal.

However, cassandra includes a bundled tool called 'sstableloader', which reads sstables from disk and writes them into a running cluster. sstableloader may be a good fit to load data from your sstables into the cluster, without worrying about the changed topology.

More info is available: http://www.pythian.com/blog/bulk-loading-options-for-cassandra/